mysql clause with 'value' not working in VSCode
If I run this query in VSCode
SELECT * FROM pr_stations_data_archive
WHERE station_nid=10449
AND sensor_id=20916
AND date_op='2023-06-12 15:33:06'
AND date_val='2022-09-07 19:00:00'
AND timezone=120
AND type_val='aver' 
AND value='24.91'
AND id_mode_value=10
AND valide='N'

it returns no data
if I comment the value clause
SELECT * FROM pr_stations_data_archive
WHERE station_nid=10449
AND sensor_id=20916
AND date_op='2023-06-12 15:33:06'
AND date_val='2022-09-07 19:00:00'
AND timezone=120
AND type_val='aver' 
-- AND value='24.91'
AND id_mode_value=10
AND valide='N'

it does return the expected line
result sql
It looks like value is a dedicated or reserved word and that it breaks the request ?
Any idea ?
commented the problematic line and expect the result wwithout having to do so

So code in backticks \value`` or rename the column. Its actually a Keyword not a Reserved word

Please add the table definition as text

Value is not a reserved word in any sql dialect that I know of..

However I can reproduce this if the value column is float(10,2)

value is indeed a reserved word. You can escape it by using backticks:
AND `value` = '24.91'

Although looking forward it might be a better idea to rename this column to something that is not a reserved word.

Thanks you all for you comments but after more tests and reseach : the fact that value is a keyword does not change anything. I did create another column 'val' with the same FLOAT value (ALTER TABLE table ADD val FLOAT;   UPDATE table SET val = value;) and this is still not possible to use this column as a clause like AND val=24.91 Some more search drived us on the fact that FLOAT cannot be used for exact reseaches, if I use AND value BETWEEN 24.9 AND 25 this works well. I don't reallu understand why, but this seems to be as simple as that
